# Connecting to Informix with NodeJS in MacOS - IBM Driver Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, macos, informix

I am attempting to connect to my **Informix** database via **NodeJS** on **MacOS**, something I would have thought was reasonably simple. However, after Googling the issue, it seems that I am required to download a driver from IBM themselves, and this is the start of the problems...

I have seen the [ifx_db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifx_db) and [informix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/informix) npm libraries which give instructions to download the informix SDK from IBM themselves, however any link I click on refers me to [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009130):

[image]

however I cannot seem to get to download the SDK itself, it just tries to make me download some sort of fix...

[image]

and going through this ends up with some sort of error, not being able to download anything...

[image]

Can anybody tell me if I am doing something wrong, looking in the wrong place? This is starting to become rather annoying!

**UPDATE**
I have since been able to follow down the rabbit hole to find [this download page](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/sdk-nodejs-compiler-zos/purchase#product-header-top), but I cannot actually download the thing!

Comment: That last link has nothing to do with Informix CSDK  (which is the product you need to be able to build the Node.JS module).

The error you get in the previous screen capture shows that the ID you used to log into the IBM website is not entitled to download CSDK. Can you try with one that has entitlement?

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=ifxdl        This is another place to get CSDK, but same as yours, it depends on your user id access.

Answer (score 0):

@jsagrera had it right.
[This](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=ifxdl) is a link where I Could correctly download everything, requiring IBM's specific downloader first (sigh). Things appear to be installed correctly after doing all of this.

Once the downloader is installed (Java may need updating first), it will automatically download the SDK file

Comment: I normally use the "http" option to avoid the Java installer ;)

Comment: @jsagrera I thought about that too, but I decided to just go with defaults to make it painless XD - Could you possibly help with my next problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273516/ibm-informix-driver-for-nodejs-setting-environment-variables-on-macos